# double dots in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can not find the documentation for the double dots around density

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A","B"), each=200)), rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))
print(head(df))
print(ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),      # Histogram with density instead of count on y-axis
                   binwidth=.5,
                   colour="black", fill="white") +
    geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(rating, na.rm=T)),   # Ignore NA values for mean
               color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1))
```

Do you know what operator they represent ?

**Edit**

I know what it *does* when used in a geom, I would like to know what it *is*.
For instance, the single dot operator is defined as

```
> .
function (..., .env = parent.frame()) 
{
    structure(as.list(match.call()[-1]), env = .env, class = "quoted")
}
<environment: namespace:plyr>
```

If I redefine *density*, then *..density..* has a different effect, so it seems  XX -> ..XX.. is an operator. I would like to find how it is defined.

Comment: That's the signal for `ggpolot2` to do it's own internal computation of the value rather than look for the value in the workspace.

Comment: yes I see the effect. I can replace by ..count.. to get he regular histogram. but I wonder as language construct what is it really. if I redefine the function 'density' that impacts the drawing, so fun x -> ..x.. is an operator on its own

Comment: for instance for . we have  **> .**
function (..., .env = parent.frame()) 
{
    structure(as.list(match.call()[-1]), env = .env, class = "quoted")
}
<environment: namespace:plyr>

Comment: You'll probably have to dig into the source code for `ggplot2` to find the exact definition/mechanism.

Comment: reading `?stat_bin` provides *no* insight to this question

Comment: This is a great tutorial http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/, but I have also wondered the same thing. Great question.

Comment: As of ggplot2 3.3.0, the `..var..` variables are superseded by the `after_stat()` function.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unlike many other languages, in R, the dot is perfectly valid in identifiers. In this case, `..count..` is an identifier. However, there is special code in `ggplot2` to detect this pattern, and to strip the dots. It feels unlikely that real code would use identifiers formatted like that, and so this is a neat way to distinguish between defined and calculated aesthetics.

The relevant code is at the end of [layer.r](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/layer.r):

```
# Determine if aesthetic is calculated
is_calculated_aes <- function(aesthetics) {
  match <- "\\.\\.([a-zA-z._]+)\\.\\."
  stats <- rep(FALSE, length(aesthetics))
  grepl(match, sapply(aesthetics, deparse))
}

# Strip dots from expressions
strip_dots <- function(aesthetics) {
  match <- "\\.\\.([a-zA-z._]+)\\.\\."
  strings <- lapply(aesthetics, deparse)
  strings <- lapply(strings, gsub, pattern = match, replacement = "\\1")
  lapply(strings, function(x) parse(text = x)[[1]]) 
}
```

It is used further up above in the `map_statistic` function. If a calculated aesthetic is present, another data frame (one that contains e.g. the `count` column) is used for the plot.

The single dot `.` is just another identifier, defined in the `plyr` package. As you can see, it is a function.

Comment: awesome. so this is reflection based wizardry. good to know as I imagine it represent a whole pattern in some R libs, and provides one documented entry point in ggplot.

Comment: @nicolas: I'm not sure if the term "reflection" applies here. `ggplot2` is simply looking at the data and taking different action if the data is formatted in a certain way.

Comment: well the binding is not static, and is computed on the fly, based on some attribute. may be it is not reflection, but it looks close to it.

Comment: In the ggplot2 package, the double dots approach will be replaced by the  `calc()` function.  Instead of using `..density..` to indicate that you want to use the density of the inherited aesthetic, you can use `calc(density)`.  I don't believe this is in the distribution version as the writing of this comment.
 https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/2184d962b2326ffab0cec4977b22795df004c149/R/aes-calculated.r

Comment: Actually, I just stumbled onto this. And they renamed the `calc` function to `stat` in ggplot2 3 (Which seems to be a more fitting name)

Comment: Now it's called `after_stat`. Variables documented in "Computed variables" sections of the docs tell you what you can use with it. Example usage: `geom_hex(aes(fill=after_stat(log1p(count))))`. 

Excited to see what it's called next year!