# What does ..count.. mean in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking at the documentation for `ggplot2`, in particular [this page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html), and am trying to parse the examples, in particular,

```
cars <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=factor(cyl), x=mpg))
cars + stat_bin(aes(fill=..count..), geom="tile", binwidth=3, position="identity")
```

I don't understand the notation, `fill=..count..`. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc) help?

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17506197/946850) for some technical detail.

Comment: @krlmlr, much nicer link and nice answer, +1 to both.