# Faceted density histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot two histograms side-by-side, showing the density of each observation value under each condition.

For example, if I have the following data frame:

```
> (test <- data.frame(rain=c(T,T,T,F,F), bikes=as.integer(c(1,1,2,1,2)), location=as.factor(c('a','b','a','b','b'))))
   rain bikes location
1  TRUE     1        a
2  TRUE     1        b
3  TRUE     2        a
4 FALSE     1        b
5 FALSE     2        b
```

Then I want to draw a histogram for rain=FALSE with two bars of height 0.5; and another for rain=TRUE with bars of height 1/3 and 2/3.

I've tried this

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=bikes, y=..density..)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_discrete() + 
  facet_wrap(~rain) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.05))
```

and it gives the correct shape, but every bar is about 10% too tall:

[image: Bad density picture]

I've also tried `y=..count../sum(..count..)`, but there the bar heights are 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2 - it seems to be summing over the whole data frame, not just the `rain` condition.

(I don't really get the `..foo..` syntax. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502808/double-dots-in-a-ggplot), but I still don't get where `density` and `count` come from.)

I know I could create a temporary data frame to plot instead, but I prefer to avoid that - doing everything from the same data frame feels more flexible for things I might want to do in future - and I haven't come up with a non-awful way of doing it.

Ideally, I'd also like to color the bars by `location`. If I do that with `..density..`, I get this result:

[image]

where the statistic's apparently been calculated over each of four conditions (rain-a, rain-b, dry-a, dry-b). I want it only calculated over the rain/dry condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyo, it's much easier to modify your data frame in order to get R to do what you want. Using the `plyr` package:

```
❥ library(plyr)
❥ test2 <- ddply(test, .(rain), transform, proportion = 1/length(rain))
❥ test2
   rain bikes location proportion
1 FALSE     1        b     0.5000
2 FALSE     2        b     0.5000
3  TRUE     1        a     0.3333
4  TRUE     1        b     0.3333
5  TRUE     2        a     0.3333
❥ ggplot(test2, aes(x=bikes)) + geom_bar(aes(y = proportion), stat= "identity") + facet_grid(~rain) + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:max(test2$bikes))
```

[image: corrected plot]