# Please explain ..density

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm reading a book on R, and one of the commands is

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, y = ..density..)) +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(color = cut), binwidth = 500)
```

The book explains that the graph shows the density of `price`, but it doesn't explain what the two dots around `density` are, and I haven't had any luck searching the documentation.  What do the two dots do, and how should I know that I need to use them in this situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502808/double-dots-in-a-ggplot

Comment: Thanks. I'll read through that answer.

Comment: if p is your plot. Then do `g = ggplot_build(p)`. This shows variables that ggplot generates for plotting: see `head(g$data[[1]])`. You can access these variables to use by surrounding with the dots. try also with `..width.. ,   ..ncount.. , ..ndensity.., ..PANEL.. ` etc

Comment: Interesting.  That's really helpful.  Thank you.